# Java file storage implementation

Tags: java, mongodb, jackrabbit, dms

I would like to create small [DMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) in java. I will need for this some storage which will store only binary data. I found [jackrabbit](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/index.html) or [gridfs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) could help me to create something like filestore/repository, but don't know if that will be good enough.

I need:

- Storage which will return ID on first save
- If possible, save additional metadata of file
- Versioning
- Query for the document
- Possibility to sync content between many servers

What could be advantages of using something like jackrabbit or gridfs (or if there's better solution)? I know that there exists some free DMS systems like [alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/community) but that's overkill for my needs.

Comment: Sounds to me a bit like reinventing the wheel. ;-) Jackrabbit (or other [JCR](http://www.day.com/day/en/products/jcr/jsr-283.html) implementation, such as [ModeShape](http://modeshape.jboss.org/) should provide the required features. Anyway, I would recommend to have a look on [Magnolia CMS](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/), which is free, open source, well-documented, and the [Digital Asset Management](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Digital+asset+management) module gives you all the needed functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Jackrabbit (or rather its more modern successor, [Oak](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/)) will do all this, and Oak can use MongoDB as its storage backend (I mention this as you have tagged your question with "mongodb"). Using it together with [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/) provides you with a flexible content management framework.